# How to prove convergence of $a_n$ if $(n+1)(a_{n+1}-a_n)=n(a_{n-1}-a_n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Could you give me some hint how to conclude convergence of $a_n$ from 
this feature : $$(n+1)(a_{n+1}-a_n)=n(a_{n-1}-a_n)$$

From $$(n+1)(a_{n+1}-a_n)=n(a_{n-1}-a_n)$$ we may conclude that $$a_n=(n+1)a_{n+1}-na_{n-1}$$
but I failed to realize how to continue.

Thanks.

Comment: With some diagonalisation argument I think you can find a closed form for $a_n$; exactly like for Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: @Joe. There is a closed form for $a_n$; it involves the Lerch function. This is a beautiful problem. Cheers.

Comment: I think this question is identical to this one:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113086/if-n1a-n1-a-n-na-n-1-a-n-for-all-natural-n-then-a-n-converges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(-1)^n n(a_{n-1}-a_n)$ is a constant.

In other words:

$$
a_{n-1}-a_n = (-1)^n \frac C{n}
$$

And the series of term $(-1)^n \frac C{n}$ is convergent. Hence $a$ is convergent too.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{n}{n+1}=\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{a_{n-1}-a_n}\\a_{n-1}-a_n>a_{n+1}-a_n\\a_{n-1}>a_{n+1}$$
In this kind of problems mostly you don't really need the explicit formula for $a_n$ you need the relation between elemenets.

EDIT:I forgot to say that this works if $a_{n-1}\not=a_n$

Now if we take $$a_n>a_{n+1}\\(n+1)a_{n+1}-na_{n-1}>a_{n+1}\\na_{n+1}>na_{n-1}\\a_{n+1}>a_{n-1} \implies a_n<a_{n+1}\implies a_{n-1}<a_n<a_{n+1}$$
Which is incorrect,so $a_{n-1}=a_n$,so $a_n=C$

Comment: So, $a_{2m}$ is decreasing and bounded below by $a_2$ , therefore $a_{2m}\to a_2$, and $a_{2m+1}$ is decreasing and bounded below by $a_1$ , therefore $a_{2m+1}\to a_1$, but how do you now $a_1=a_2$ ?

Comment: Take a look at my edit,I made a mistake.